# Duration validation in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to validate a cell in google sheet. This cell should be in format

`"hh:mm:ss"` where `ss` is optional.

I used the below formula, it returns the same for `"1:02"` and `"1.2"
=regexmatch(text(F3,"hh:mm"), "[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$")`

I want to distinguish between `:` and `.` If user enters 'DOT' `.` then it should highlight it as wrong and only COLON `:`.

Comment: BTW, I am working with google spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you format it before with a colon.
`1.02` is equal to to `01:02 hours`.
`1.2` is equal to `04.48` hours as it 1.2 days.
You need to validate the raw text.

Set the cell format to Plain text and change the validation to

```
=regexmatch(F3, "[0-1]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9](?:\:[0-5]?[0-9])?")
```

This will accept durations such as:

- 1:02
- 1:2 (one hour and two minutes)
- 01:02
- 01:02:35
- 1:2:5 (one hour, two minutes and five seconds)

Just remove the lazy quantifiers if you don't want to allow non-leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you want it to apply to the whole column or range that has the values in it.

If you want to use data validation to mark or reject the value, you can put this as your "custom function" for data valdation:

```
=IF(counta(split(indirect(address(row(),1)),"."))>1,false,true)
```

or if you just want to conditionally format to color the incorrect cells, then choose conditional formatting, choose custom function and enter in this formula:

```
=IF(counta(split(indirect(address(row(),1)),"."))>1,true,false)
```